# Storage variable for cache

Tags: javascript

What do I need to insert in this script for the variable to be cached and after I refresh the page in the browser, the variable stays the same?

```js
   <script>
   var WishCounter = 0;
   $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".accordion-heading").click(function(){
                if($(".accordion-body").is(':visible')){  /* check the condition accordion-body is visible or not */
                    $(".accordion-body").slideUp(200);  /*if content is visible then close accordion-body with specific time duration */
                  $(".plusminus").text('+')    /* add plus sign */
              }
              else{
                  $(this).next(".accordion-body").slideDown(200); /*if content not visible then
                                                                                                              show the accordion-body */
                  $(this).children(".plusminus").text('-');  /* add minus sign */
              }
          });
          $(".add-to-cart2").click(function(){
              WishCounter++;
              localStorage.setItem('WishCounter', WishCounter);
              $(".cart-wish").text(WishCounter);
              localStorage.getItem('WishCounter')



          });
      });

      </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Persist variables between page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/persist-variables-between-page-loads)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but the simplest way with the least setup required is [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). It works as a Map, and persists upon browser refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for this. It allows you to store data in the browser and it will persist even after closing the window.

Every time you modify `WishCounter` call `localStorage.setItem('WishCounter', WishCounter);`

When you start the website just call `localStorage.getItem('WishCounter');` to get the data.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that you need to define `localStorage` as `window.localStorage` (`let localStorage = window.localStorage`)

Comment: I rewrote the code above, I put it in the website but unfortunately it does not work, probably something I do not do well. Can you please tell me exactly how to insert the lines of code provided by you?

Comment: You are setting wishcounter back to 0 right before you get it every time

Answer (score 0):

Localstorage is used for data with no expiration date, however sessionstorage is only stored for one session. To set a value to localstorage, one needs to use `localStorage.setItem(key,value);`. To get the value from localstorage, one needs to use `localStorage.getItem(key);`. However for both `setItem` and `getItem`, the value and key must be strings.